# При использовании jQuery  .on alert срабатывает 2 раза

Tags: jquery, события

```
$(document).on("click", "#one a", function(event){
    alert('1');
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему alert срабатвыает 2 раза?

Comment: Почему не так?

    $("#one a").click(function(e){
      alert('1');
    });

Comment: Ссылку в ссылку вкладываете? А скрипт вызывается один раз?

Comment: @ling Даже при вложенной ссылке сработает один раз. А вот где-то триггер у него стоять может, который вызывает событие повторно.
@Sh4dow Я думаю, что человеку нужно было создать делегированную обработку, только вот использовать в качестве parent-селектора "*document*" - как-то мне не понятно. Прямая обработка *$("#one a").click()*, в некоторых случаях, может быть не очень хорошим вариантом, поэтому введение метода **on()** в версии 1.7 имеет смысл.

Comment: @Deonis, сколько уровней вложения, столько раз и сработает. Событие всплывает, а остановки я не вижу.

Comment: @ling ))) Иногда лучше один раз увидеть, чем спорить. Персонально для вас - http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/3TqAT/

Comment: @Deonis, хм, действительно. Признаю свою ошибку, так как тестировал на div'ах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Еще может быть из-за того, что дважды подключен файл со скриптами Js. У меня такое бывало.

Answer (score 1):

Не должен срабатывать, даже, если предположить, что у вас грубая ошибка и два элемента имеют одинаковый ID **one**. Поэтому, тут надо видеть код в целом. Пока единственное предположение - это то, что вы могли указать селекторы через запятую, т.е. **"#one, a"** Тогда два срабатывания вполне реальны.